# certain images wont show up in codepen, but do show up in we3schools

Tags: html

i am trying to put an image in my document at codepen.   for some reason it shows the link as broken, yet it shows up if i try to load the image into the browser , or even in w3schools frame.

here is a link to the code,
https://codepen.io/richardengle/pen/rNMRzzE
here is the image that wont show in codepen, but will show in the browser and also in w3schools
http://ryanspickapart.com/images/credit-card-icons.png

### here is the code - note that the second image[dog] shows up fine... why wont the other image show here?

```
<img src="http://ryanspickapart.com/images/credit-card-icons.png" alt='image wont load'>
<br>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513639725746-c5d3e861f32a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80' alt='image works fine' >
```

---

Comment: Could it be that codepen doesn't allow images from "http://" to be shown but images from "https://" are secure?

Comment: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cdpn.io/richardengle/fullpage/rNMRzzE' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://ryanspickapart.com/images/credit-card-icons.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html`

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate used to sign HTTPS connections to `ryanspickapart.com` was granted to  `picknpullsa.com`.

If you attempt to access `ryanspickapart.com` via HTTPS, your browser may warn you about this mismatch:

[image: connection security warning]

And may refuse to download assets:

[image: loading error message]

This is not a problem when you are accessing the content via HTTP since the certificate is not used. Codepen is likely enforcing that you access assets via HTTPS.